# How to route Public IP?

Tags: networking, routing

We have leased a routed block of public IPs (example: 123.45.67.89, 987.65.43.21 etc.) that will be used for our 10 public web servers (eventually). These servers need to be placed outside the corporate firewall and should be accessible without using VPN. All these public IPs are on a WAN subnet that is **different** from subnet of router's WAN. The desired result is that if anyone on the internet accesses 123.45.67.89 or 987.65.43.21 from their browser, that request should hit the respective web server. Can you all please suggest how should the router be configured? Do I need to set up port forwarding?

I understand that all routers are different but a theoretical explanation will suffice. I will be happy to provide more information, if required. I am also open to suggestions to buy a specific make/model of router and/or other networking hardware to resolve this situation.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**: My previous ISP had given a block of public IPs that had subnet mask same as the router's subnet mask. Under that setup, I was able to use a switch between modem and router and connect all my web servers to the switch **before** hitting the router. So these were truly public servers having their own IP and required no VPN. I'd like to implement something similar with the current ISP that gave me two different subnet masks.

Comment: How you configured it, depends on how your ISP has provisioned the network.

Comment: A lot of how this could be configured depends on your current network topology and can also depend on the ISP. If your main WAN is 10.10.10.0/29, you might be able to set up a static route that lets the other block out the gateway of the first one, 10.10.11.0/29 10.10.10.1. This would mean that you'd have to have the interface that the second router is plugged into free of firewall/vpn/vlans.

Comment: ISP provided two subnet masks - one for our router's WAN and another for routed /27 IP block. Does this info sound helpful?

Comment: Are you also planning to setup a firewalled DMZ?

Comment: @MaQleod, I configured a static route and I am able to reach out to internet from my web server. However, the server itself is not accessible from internet (I have no port forwarding set). Any ideas how to reach the server from my phone (for example)?

Comment: @Eric G, I am not planning to setup a firewalled DMZ at this time.

Comment: Depending on your router, you can either open ports to specific IPs (sometimes only lets you direct a port to a single IP, so if you have multiple servers for the same service, you need to use different ports) or you can configure the firewall only for the necessary interfaces and leave the servers more open (and harden the servers themselves).

Comment: @MaQleod, I can direct specific ports to the servers just like you recommended but this will require a user (on internet) to access my router's IP (and that will forward traffic to respective server), correct? I'd like them to access my server's IP instead. Is this possible?

Comment: @MaQleod, please see UPDATE 1 in the original post.

Comment: Is it actually a routed block? or is it several /32 IPs that just happen to be in succession?

Comment: @MaQleod, I just looked at the documentation to confirm that. My ISP calls it a /27 "routable" block. I hope it is same as "routed" block.

Comment: @MaQleod,any other ideas?

Comment: With a routed block, you need a router to handle it. If you had just a few single IPs (/32), you could put a switch in front and manually assign the IPs on the devices connected. If the ISP has it setup to work, you could swap the blocks in the config I suggested before.